# Android MapViewCompassDemo is flickering with no title window

Tags: rotation, android-mapview, flicker, redraw

I'm trying to make **a rotated map view activity**.
I've copied the sample provided with the SDK in :

> \android-sdk\add-ons\addon-google_apis-google_inc_-3\samples\MapsDemo\src\com\example\android\apis\view

It is working quite nicely, BUT, if you only add

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

In the `public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` of the example activity, then the map flickers. I mean that it redraws and redraws again...

Any tip to avoid this ?

The issue is not visible if you have the title on the window.